# asset pipeline InternalError: too much recursion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, precompile

i m in troubles :)

Im trying to deploy an app with rails 3.2.1 and coffee-rails 3.2.2, but when the assets compilation occure, i get an internal error

```
*** [out :: ] Compiling: coffee-script.js
*** [err :: ] rake aborted!
*** [err :: ] 
*** [err :: ] InternalError: too much recursion
*** [err :: ] (in ~/project/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts/coffee-script.js.erb)
*** [err :: ] 
*** [err :: ] 
*** [err :: ] Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
*** [err :: ] 
*** [err :: ] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

i tried it locally (rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development --trace) and he don't cry ...

Can anybody help?

UPDATE:

I ve tried to compile in the production env => rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace 
and again it works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add therubyracer and execjs to my production environment.

```
group :staging, :production do
  gem "therubyracer", "0.9.9"
  gem "execjs",       "1.3.0"
end
```